# Calculate SUM without Adding Values to Rows/Columns?

Tags: excel, sum, sequence

When calculating series in Excel, most tutorials begin by setting sequence values to certain range of cells, say

```
 A1=1, A2=2, A3=3,..., A10=10
```

and to get the value of 1+2+...+10, execute

```
 A11=SUM(A1:A10)
```

But I don't want the "generate the sequence in worksheet cells first" part because initially I don't know the 'n' (10 in the above) and I want to define a custom function that takes n as a function argument.

So, is there a way to do something like this?

```
B1 = SUM([1:10])  // adding array of 'constants', not cell reference
```

EDIT: If I could 'summon' some (array of) big number(s) without any cell/ROW/COL operation as in calling rand(), that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Array Formula as below

```
=SUM(ROW(A1:A10)) and then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER
```

Row(A1:A10) will become {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}.

Comment: But what if x (As in Ax) is a really large number?

Comment: will it be more than 1048576?

Comment: I just don't get why I should fill out many cells when those values are not further used. And no, it's about calculating interest and total amount for about 50 years, with monthly deposit. Dragging 50*12=600 rows seems painful.

Comment: If you give =Row(A1), it will give you answer "1", even if A1 is empty. It gives the row number, doesn't matter if they are filled or not. So you don't need to fill any rows if you give ={SUM(ROW(A1:A10))}

Comment: =SUM(ROW(A1:A10)) yields 1, NOT 1+...+10=55. Also tried =SUM(ROW(A1):ROW(A10)), which gives an error.

Comment: Oh now I get that. What's CTRL+Shift+Enter really doing?

Comment: it converts formula into Array, kinda running in loop

Answer (score -1):

Usage:
If you want to sum cells A20 to A50

```
sumjeff("A", 20,50)
```

Code

```
Function sumJeff(letter As String, nFrom As Integer, nTo As Integer) As Double

    Dim strAddress As String
    strAddress = letter & nFrom & ":" & letter & nTo
    sumJeff = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(strAddress))

End Function
```